# Laravel how to add variables or properties to mail notifiables

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I had a very simple problem because I am new to Laravel. My question is how can I echo the name of the applicant for the mail message?

Here is the code:

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        $name = $notifiable->name;

        return (new MailMessage)
                    ->from('testing@gmail.com', 'Test')
                    ->greeting('Hello!')
                    ->line('You are receiving this email because we received a password request for your account.')
                    ->action('Click here to Reset Password', route('applicant.reset', $this->token))
                    ->line('If you did not reset your password, no further action is required.');
    }
```

The output should be "Hello! (Applicant Name here)" and when I try to `dd` it, it gives me the correct output of the applicant who reset his password.

But when I include this in my code:

```
->greeting('Hello! $name')
```

It gives me "Hello! $name" when I receive the email, which is the code verbatim.

Comment: Try `->greeting('Hello!' .$name)`

Comment: That ends the discussion. Thankyou so much! Appreciated it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

`->greeting('Hello!' .$name)`

Instead of

```
->greeting('Hello! $name')
```

Hope this works!

Comment: Thanks! wait for 9 minutes to accept the answer. Hehe appreciated it!

Comment: Ok, Glad to help you! :)

Comment: There! Sorry got a little bit busy in schoo. Btw. Thanks!

Comment: btw can I ask something? Maybe in the chatroom? If it is okay?

Comment: Yes please ask!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153187/discussion-between-jayz-de-vera-and-hiren-gohel).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use double quotes and variable interpolation.

```
->greeting("Hello! $name")
```

or better

```
->greeting("Hello! ${name}")
```

> If a dollar sign ($) is encountered, the parser will greedily take as many tokens as possible to form a valid variable name. Enclose the variable name in curly braces to explicitly specify the end of the name.

[Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.simple).